# Null Condition with current month condition

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, left-join

i am trying to run a mysql select query where i want to fetch the students who did not pay the fee at current month. please check my condition if i use these one by one it works but they both at same time dont work

```
"SELECT A.studentid,A.stu_first_name,A.stu_last_name,
 A.stu_reg_no,A.phone,
 B.submit_on,
 C.class_name FROM students as A 
 LEFT JOIN student_fee as B on A.studentid = B.student_id 
 inner join class as C on 
 A.class_id=C.classid 
 WHERE MONTH(B.submit_on) = MONTH(NOW()) 
 AND B.student_id IS NULL"
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! We really need a [mcve]. Can you [edit] one in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to move the condition of `B.submit_on` from the `WHERE` clause to the `LEFT JOIN` on table `B`. Otherwise, records where there is no match in `B` are filtered out by the `WHERE` clause, which I believe is the opposite of what you want (this actually turns your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`).

```
SELECT 
    A.studentid,
    A.stu_first_name,
    A.stu_last_name,
    A.stu_reg_no,
    A.phone,
    B.submit_on,
    C.class_name
FROM 
    students as A 
    LEFT JOIN student_fee as B on A.studentid = B.student_id AND MONTH(B.submit_on) = MONTH(NOW()) 
    INNER JOIN class as C ON A.class_id = C.classid 
WHERE B.student_id IS NULL"
```